# Why is my useEffect() not running on change or page refresh - React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

[image: This is where I access the Details state][image: Screenshot]

The Firebase query I have created is working perfectly fine as it returns the correct data. I have access to the correct information, but my table is not displaying the data because the function getUsers() is not running by default or even a page refresh. I am still new with React js, so take it easy on me please lol

Comment: Do you put those `useEffect` after the `return` statement?

Comment: UseEffect and useState should be at the top level.
I think the function getUsers is also wrong. setDetails(obj) should be outside the foreach
`function  getUsers () {
query.forEach() { your code}
}`

Comment: `function  getUsers () {
query.forEach() { your code}
 setDetails(obj)
}`
}`

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Hi, will do that in the future my apologies. The problem was that the setDetails() was in the wrong place lol

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
useEffect(() => getUsers(),[Details]);
```

Adding your state as the dependency should allow it run every time the state changes

Answer (score 1):

The `useEffect` hook with an empty dependency array will only run in the `onMount` lifecycle phase of the component, that means only once. If you want it to run on every render, remove the dependency array like:

```
useEffect(() => getUsers());
```

Comment: I tried that but my application closes down due to too many renders

Comment: then u have another problem, it cannot run on every re-render, how often or when do u need the updated data?

Comment: I need it to run onMount and then after a item has been added (to see the newly inserted item on the table)